# Carriage return after a rectangle

Tags: plantuml

I have the following definition in which I need to have all two inner rectangles in vertical layout, instead of horizontal like in the below image;

[image]

```
@startuml

rectangle "AAAAAA" {

  rectangle "CCCCCC" {
    CDE --> (AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA)
    CDE --> (BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB)
    CDE ---> (CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC)
    CDE ---> (DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD)
    CDE ----> (EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE)
    CDE ----> (FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
    CDE ----> (GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG)
  }

  rectangle "BBBBBB" {
    ABC-down-> (AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA)
    ABC -> (BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB)
    ABC --> (CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC)
  }
}

@enduml
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve it with a really crazy trick, I was trying to control layout with a hidden arrow;

- I put `left to right direction`, since with normal direction [I was unable to achieve exact vertical ordering](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/RT6n2i8m4CRn_PxYw6I7l88qIQiF8Gx52ohK23NY87rtqvD2UjVVUFo7yALvfNvCxyS0C8PBwkDr25XPLk4N0B6uUpRVCVDjXyRiSMULUXqufGYuy98CMgaCkEWaLHmaLHmtpD4aXd1i6S8wR-ZvYPjRr4k2UWbM16e9zd_01E0OcjFjJXJYcNBl6JGXKlx57m00)
- I reversed the direction of hidden arrow `BB -[hidden]d-> CC`

Though with different data it might get messy, do let me know if your real example works or not.

[Working example](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/RT4n2eCm5CRn_PtYmwaEkKBHHDj3b0xIf1gm4MoaG_7kDGOXJVAVvF4Rv4lrjjribzT8etfQs0cpxWSBgMVri7eoHEwZC_seKDHx1Rv4G70NU-wEBT6qOEoCKvrK_WEU508dH5mCchW0UD769U8IbuXh9eVMQ0Y-TmnHSy7az37PBSg38By43q1s2U5_O2No7kmsQ2cLkI-RzuGgPUJskZy0)